# AHK Radio button value not getting passed

Tags: autohotkey

My radio button value is not getting passed to my goto handle. I reviewed videos and peoples examples and do not see what I'm missing here. From examples it looks like this is valid and I can call on the vVariable thing to see what radio is selected.

```
Gui, Add, Button, x+5 hp gInstaller,Create
;Radio buttons
Gui, Add, Radio, x135 y+10 Group vProda, HCO
Gui, Add, Radio, x+10 vProdb Checked, NPM
Gui, Add, Radio, x+10 vProdc, SAM


Gui, Show, w500 h500, AHK Super GUI
return

ButtonOK:
Gui, submit, nohide



Installer:
    msgbox % Proda "|" Prodb "|" Prodc
```

[image]

Comment: There is no OK button. Put the `submit` command under the label `Installer`.

Answer (score 0):

It needs this `Gui, submit, nohide` thing after the goto handle I found.

```
Gui, Add, Button, x+5 hp gInstaller,Create
;Radio buttons
Gui, Add, Radio, x135 y+10 Group vProda, HCO
Gui, Add, Radio, x+10 vProdb Checked, NPM
Gui, Add, Radio, x+10 vProdc, SAM


Gui, Show, w500 h500, AHK Super GUI
return

ButtonOK:
Gui, submit, nohide



Installer:
    Gui, submit, nohide
    msgbox % Proda "|" Prodb "|" Prodc
```